# Why won't my program display the .png it receives from the user as a form input?

Tags: javascript

I have a program that uses a form to receive a .png file from the user, which is then dynamically set as an img. The form seems to allow me to select a file, but does not display that file. I was under the assumption that I could set the src for the img as the variable(wscimginput) associated with the user's file, but that does not seem to be working? Is there another way I should approach this?

Here's the piece of code dealing with the form and the image.

```js
var wscimgform = document.createElement("form");
 var wscimginput = document.createElement("input");
 wscimgform.appendChild(wscimginput);
 _wsc.appendChild(wscimgform);
 wscimginput.setAttribute("id", "wscimginput");
 wscimginput.setAttribute("type", "file");
 wscimginput.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
 var wscimg = document.createElement("img");
 _wsc.appendChild(wscimg);
 wscimg.setAttribute("src", "wscimginput");
 wscimg.setAttribute("position", "absolute");
 wscimg.setAttribute("height", "80%");
 wscimg.setAttribute("top", "20%");
```

Comment: You are setting the `src` attribute to the string `"wscimginput"` ...

Comment: Have a look here [link](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/display-preview-selected-image-in-input-type-file-using-jqueryexample.html) for an example on how to wire up a preview of the user selected image.

Comment: @Forty3 Just tried removing the "" so that it's not a string, but the console still tells me the error File Not Found?

Comment: @Forty3 Is there a way to do it without jquery?

Answer (score 1):

This is adapted from the linked article without jQuery.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="formDiv">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var f = document.createElement("form");
            var fi = document.createElement("input");
            fi.setAttribute("id", "daFile");
            fi.setAttribute("type", "file");
            fi.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
            fi.addEventListener("change", showPreview);

            f.appendChild(fi);

            var i = document.createElement("img");
            i.setAttribute("id", "daImg");
            i.setAttribute("width", "200px");
            i.setAttribute("height", "200px");

            f.appendChild(i);

            document.getElementById("formDiv").appendChild(f);

            function showPreview(ev) {
                if (ev.target.files && ev.target.files[0]) {
                    var r = new FileReader();
                    r.onload = function (e) {
                        document.getElementById("daImg").setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
                    }
                    r.readAsDataURL(ev.target.files[0]);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```